# Pine Code: Extending high and low price lines from last session

Tags: pine-script, trading, technical-indicator

I'm trying to write a simple script that shows the previous Monday's high and low price. For some reason that I cannot figure out, it refers to the highs and lows from *two* Mondays ago.

First, we define the session (I only want prices from the NY session):

```
InSession(sessionTime, sessionTimeZone=syminfo.timezone) =>
    not na(time(timeframe.period, sessionTime, sessionTimeZone))

daysInput = input.string("2", title="Session Days", group="Trading Session",
     tooltip="Specify active days. 1=Sunday.")

sessionInput = input.session("0930-2230", title="Session Times", 
     group="Trading Session")

sessionTime = sessionInput + ":" + daysInput

sessionZone = input.string("UTC-4", title="Session time zone")
```

Step 2, instantiate the variables:

```
var float monday_high_price = na
var float monday_low_price = na
var sessionHighPrice = 0.0
var sessionLowPrice  = 0.0
var sessionOpenPrice = 0.0
var sessionClosePrice = 0.0
var sessionMidPrice = 0.0
```

Step 3, See if the session is currently active and just started. When a new session starts, set the session high and low to the data of the bar in the session.

```
inSession    = InSession(sessionTime, sessionZone) and timeframe.isintraday
sessionStart = inSession and not inSession[1]

if sessionStart
    sessionHighPrice := high
    sessionLowPrice  := low
    sessionOpenPrice := open
    sessionClosePrice := close
// Else, during the session, track the highest high and lowest low
else if inSession
    sessionHighPrice := math.max(sessionHighPrice, high)
    sessionLowPrice  := math.min(sessionLowPrice, low)
```

Step 4, draw the lines for the high/low price for the previous Monday. If a new high/low is observed while in session, update the high/low price.

```
if sessionStart and dayofweek.monday
    var line monday_high_line = line.new(na, na, na, na, extend=extend.right, color=color.green)
    line.set_xy1(monday_high_line, bar_index, monday_high_price)
    line.set_xy2(monday_high_line, bar_index+1, monday_high_price)
    monday_high_price := high

    var line monday_low_line = line.new(na, na, na, na, extend=extend.right, color=color.green)
    line.set_xy1(monday_low_line, bar_index, monday_low_price)
    line.set_xy2(monday_low_line, bar_index+1, monday_low_price)
    monday_low_price := low

if inSession
    if (high >= monday_high_price)
        monday_high_price := high
    if (low <= monday_low_price)
        monday_low_price := low
```

The price lines start at the beginning of the last observed session, as intended, but the prices levels are from two sessions ago. Please help!

[Screenshot of indicator on TradingView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COmQL.png)